# can not resolve Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

i am trying to declare Firebase but it's giving error can not resolve Firebase.
i have added all the dependencies. when typing in android studio FirebaseDatabase etc are available but simple Firebase is not.
here are my dependencies

```
enter code here
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.doctor.lenovo.mvprecovery"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the lastest version of Google Repository (You can update to a newer version in SDK Manager tab)

Comment: Google repositories rev 41

Comment: i double checked but i have the latest one...
please solve my problem

Comment: Also google play services v38 installed? can you post the whole app-gardle file here?

Comment: i edit the question again with whole app-gradle file @Yakirbu

Comment: is it possible that..Firebase keyword is changed to FirebaseApp

Comment: Nope, I'm using Firebase just as you complied in your gardle file and it works fine. The only problem I can think of is updating versions in SDK Manager, because your gardle file is fine. Also, you didn't forget to add 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'' to the project gardle, right?

Comment: yes i also added classpath into project build gradel

Comment: i uninstalled repositories, google play services  and reinstalled it but still does't work